# Make containers inside network unroutable from the host

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

For a testing situation, I've created a docker-compose file which stands up two containers:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  foo:
    ports:
      - 5000:5000/tcp
    networks:
      - default
    ...

  bar:
    networks:
      - default
    ...

networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: internal
      config:
        - subnet: 172.100.0.0/16
```

For the purposes of my tests, I need `bar` to be unreachable from the host.  Unfortunately, when I run `docker-compose up`, `ip addr` shows that my host is on that network at `172.100.0.1`.

How do I change my YAML file to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Caveat** The address range you've selected (172.100.0.0/16) is a *routeable* address range that apparently belongs to [charter communications](https://ipinfo.io/AS11351/172.100.0.0/15). This means that attempts to reach addresses in that range -- if there's not a specific route to your containers -- will get routed via your default gateway and potentially to actual machines somewhere on the internet.

---

Anyway, to your question:

I don't believe this is going to be possible using only Docker. For a bridged network, Docker will (a) always create a host bridge and (b) always assign an ip address to that bridge, which means containers will always be routable from the host.

You can create containers that have **no** network connectivity by using the `none` network:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  foo:
    network_mode: none
    image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd

  bar:
    network_mode: none
    image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd
```

And then manually wire them up to a bridge using `ip` commands:

```
ip link add br-internal type bridge
ip link set br-internal up

foo_pid="$(docker inspect project_foo_1 --format '{{ .State.Pid }}')"
bar_pid="$(docker inspect project_bar_1 --format '{{ .State.Pid }}')"

ln -s /proc/$foo_pid/ns/net /run/netns/foo
ln -s /proc/$bar_pid/ns/net /run/netns/bar

ip link add foo-ext type veth peer name foo-int netns foo
ip -n foo addr add 172.100.0.10/26 dev foo-int
ip -n foo link set foo-int up
ip link set foo-ext up master br-internal

ip link add bar-ext type veth peer name bar-int netns bar
ip -n bar addr add 172.100.0.11/26 dev bar-int
ip -n bar link set bar-int up
ip link set bar-ext up master br-internal
```

Now we can ping `bar` from `foo`:

```
$ docker compose exec foo ping -c1 172.100.0.11
PING 172.100.0.11 (172.100.0.11): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.100.0.11: seq=0 ttl=42 time=0.080 ms

--- 172.100.0.11 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.080/0.080/0.080 ms
```

And `foo` from `bar`:

```
$ docker compose exec bar ping -c1 172.100.0.10
PING 172.100.0.10 (172.100.0.10): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.100.0.10: seq=0 ttl=42 time=0.047 ms

--- 172.100.0.10 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.047/0.047/0.047 ms
```

But our host doesn't have a route to either of these addresses:

```
$ ip route get 172.100.0.10
172.100.0.10 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.175 uid 1000
    cache
```

That shows that attempts to reach addresses on this network will get routed via our default gateway, rather than to the containers.